# How to add a resource to an activity?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dynamics-crm-2011

**Is it possible to add a resource (user / facility) to an serviceappointment?**

Here's my record to which I want to add resources:

```
        var serviceAppointment = this.organizationService.Retrieve(
            "serviceappointment",
            serviceActivityGuid,
            new ColumnSet(true));
```

I have a list of resources:

```
{
  "ListOfResourceIds": [
    {
      "partyid": "9CDC2C51-6417-4550-A0FE-D825EE75D333"
    },
    {
      "partyid": "9CDC2C51-6417-4550-A0FE-D825EE75D044"
    }
  ]
}
```

**How would I add these resources to ServiceAppointment above?**

I suspect that after adding them, I would call:

```
        organizationService.Update(serviceAppointment);
```

Answer (score 1):

Resources are of the type [ActivityParty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328549.aspx) (SystemUser). To update the service appointment, get the corresponding system user ids of the resources:

```
var serviceAppointment = organizationService.Retrieve(
                      "serviceappointment",
                      serviceActivityGuid,
                      new ColumnSet(true));

var updateServiceAppointment = new Entity("serviceappointment")
{
    Id = serviceAppointment.Id
};
updateServiceAppointment["resources"] = new[]
{
    new ActivityParty()
    {
        PartyId = new CrmEntityReference("systemuser", correspondingSystemUserId)
    }
};
organizationService.Update(updateServiceAppointment);
```

Comment: thank you very much! would this obliterate everything in the "resources" and replace with that 1 ActivityParty record?